# Angular Promises and DataService

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I have an angular data service that looks like this:

```
//dataservice.js
export class DataService {
    constructor($rootScope, $http, $q, $log) {
        $log.info('DataService constructor', this);
        this.$http = $http;
    }
        fetch(url){
        return this.$http.jsonp(url, {params: {callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'}});
    }

 }
```

If I call this from my Controller like this:

```
DataService.fetch('https://passbook-manager.jsapps.io/api/v1/passes');
```

It returns a promise that looks like this:

```
 Promise {$$state: Object, success: function, error: function, then: function, catch: function…}$$state: Objecterror: function (fn) {success: function (fn)  {__proto__: Object
```

How can I get the value of the promise and return it so that I can update my scope ?

I've tried this but it does not return any data:

```
DataService.fetch('https://passbook-manager.jsapps.io/api/v1/passes').then(function( val ) {
  $scope.val = val;
  console.log(val) 
});
```

Comment: The problem is that API your are using does not implement JSONP.

Comment: Perfect - that sorted it thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OK so the problem as explained by @dfsq was the API. It didn't support JSONP. Changed my code to:

```js
    return this.$http.get(url, {params: {callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'}});
```

It then worked perfectly.